# nginx server: how to remove first directory from URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

Can anybody please help me to remove first directory name from URL?

My Image location is `_data/hotel/3/15377/hotel_image.jpg`

But Image path gets changed due to relative URL in code and it become to something like this.

`example.com/france/_data/hotel/3/15377/hotel_image.jpg`
`example.com/usa/_data/hotel/3/15377/hotel_image.jpg`
`example.com/india/_data/hotel/3/15377/hotel_image.jpg`

is their any possibilities to remove dynamic country name from above URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to rewrite only this particular URL, you can use this `location` block in your config:

```
location ~ /[a-z]+/_data/hotel/3/15377/hotel_image.jpg {
    try_files /_data/hotel/3/15377/hotel_image.jpg;
}
```

If you want to rewrite all URLs which lead to `/<country>/_data/...`, you can use:

```
location ~ /[a-z]+/_data/(.+) {
    try_files /_data/$1;
}
```

or for stricter URL checking:

```
location ~ /(?:france|usa|india)/_data/(.+) {
    try_files /_data/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ivan Shatsky's answer is great for files but also if we want to redirect a general url is better if you use the `rewrite` directive.

Depending where you define the `rewrite` directive you have two ways to implement it:

#### A. In the `server` context

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/[a-z]+/_data/(.+)$ /_data/$1 last;
    ...
}
```

#### B. In the `location` context

```
location ~ /[a-z]+/_data/(.+) {
    rewrite ^/[a-z]+/_data/(.+)$ /_data/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

**Teo, why did you change the flag to `break`?*** Because, if this directive is put inside of a `location` context, the `last` flag might make `nginx` to run 10 cycles and return the 500 error.

### Note:

Remember not add `/` at the end of the `proxy_pass` directive. This example **wont work**:

```
...
proxy_pass http://backend/;
...
```